# Can I safely ignore Proguard's "duplicate definition of library class" when building Android project

Tags: java, android, eclipse, adt, proguard

I have received many warnings of `duplicate definition` like..

```
[proguard] Note: duplicate definition of library class [javax.crypto.KeyGeneratorSpi]
```

I am using proguard with Android project, unless I have added `-ignorewarnings` in the config, I was not able to build the app.

But can I safely ignore these warnings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This message is just a note, not a warning. ProGuard doesn't stop processing when there are notes, but, by default, it does stop processing when there are warnings.

Cfr. ProGuard manual > [Troubleshooting](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html) to see whether the notes or warnings are serious. For an application built using the Android SDK: if it already works in debug mode, everything is probably ok.